# Composer-rest-server command in chaincodes

Tags: rest, server, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I start my Hyperledger learning using the composer environment and getting up a node.js backend to be able to generate web request using Postman. But now,  I'm been doing the [Hyperledger Fabric first network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html) tutorial. The environment is ready and the simple chaincode in golang has been deployed in both peers. I can generate operations and query the result. But now I'm a lit in doubt. Did we have something like *composer-rest-server* command to build an operative chaincode rest api?

With *composer-rest-server* I mean [this](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/interacting-with-hyperledger-composer-through-restful-api/). Maybe Im confusing the concepts and deploying a via composer with the generated card the composer-rest-server command is able to generate the API but doing in this way is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperledger Composer (Which is now end of life) was a complete application framework comprising of an application framework api and modelling language plus a set of tools, application generators and a rest server, all designed to work together, so the rest server will only work in conjunction with a composer business network.

Hyperledger fabric doesn't have any ability to generate a rest server from any smart contract implementation, you need to create your own rest server with your own concepts of access control around it which interacts with your smart contract via either one of the hyperledger fabric sdks or your could (if you are feeling adventurous) do direct grpc interactions with a fabric network and use whatever language has grpc support.